# Div has another pixel on height for no reason

Tags: css

I couldn't figure out where does this 1px height difference in chrome 2 px height difference in firefox and ie9 is coming from ? Seems like div.entry is where it's coming from, but I couldn't fix it.

http://goo.gl/kM3U3

```
#middle {width:900px;}
#middle div.homepage img {width:900px;}
```

Comment: Where exactly am I looking for this difference?

Comment: Have you tried removing the space after the image in your code? `<div class="homepage"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage.jpg" alt="Homepage" title="Homepage"/> </div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`#middle div.homepage img {width:900px;}`

to

`#middle div.homepage img {display: block; width:900px;}`

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be a space at the end of the img tag on your site.

Comment: I checked if there is any space in coding or content but I wasn't able to find any.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem with this approach:

```
<div class="homepage" style="line-height:0">
  <img title="Homepage" alt="Homepage" src="/wp-content/uploads/Homepage.jpg">
</div>
```

The problem is that you have a line below the image, probably a `\n` or a `blank space` on the document source!

To solve issues like this, you can set the `line-height` to `0`.

Comment: Didn't solve the problem but thanks ! adding display:block solved the problem (@rob). Therefore; I added img{display:block;} in my reset.css now. Every image should be displayed as a block element anyways.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes a problem like this it's related with borders. IE, Firefox and Chrome have some minor differences with the default border so you have to establish one. 
In this case, the **css-reset.css** has set something that seems you don't want.

Change:

```
line-height: 1;
```

to:

```
line-height: 0;
```

The extra white line under the picture won't be there anymore, but I don't know if this can cause some other unwanted issues to your page.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the default options in each browser make a minor diffrence.

I never make a site without the [Reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) style sheet.

It does precisely that, resets all the defaults to a new common base, so that everything applied henceforth, should behave the same in each browser.